# Introduction to Topological Manifolds: Problem Suggestions

Tags: self-learning, problem-solving

I am currently working through the book *Introduction to Topological Manifolds* by Lee. I am doing this by myself and not following a course.

Until now I have found it a good practice to go through the exercises in the text by myself (as the author recommended in the preface), but coming to the problem section at the end of a chapter, the sheer number of problems feels overwhelming.

I think that the problems that are used throughout the text should be solved, but is that enough?

How many problems should one solve (and which ones) in order to be convinced that he has understood the material? I have read that there are people that use this book as a basis for a graduate course, but I have not been able to find a summary of the problems that have been handed out as bomework.

**My question is**: How many or which problems from the end of a chapter should one at the minimum solve?

Comment: The book is a gem. I self-studied this book--twice-- and still go back trying to do the exercises. I do the ones that "seem basic" and from there, the ones that seem "interesting." And the exercises in the body of the text are definitely a must. Yes, they do detract from the flow of the topics: I found it frustrating to have to stop reading a proof to do the exercise that was necessary to proceed or finish. I wished there were fewer of these in the text! In short, I would do all the exercises in the body of the text and then go to the ones at the end of the chapters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might be interested in the [list of problems I assigned](http://sites.math.washington.edu/%7Elee/Courses/544-2019/hw.html) the last time I taught the course.

Comment: Thank you, such a list is exactly what I was looking for! Even though I plan to do all the problems sometime, a starting point really changes the motivation of a student.